# How to add a radar chart to Views?

Tags: 7, views, charts

I'm using the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module to create a chart in my view (using its Views integration). But the supported chart type doesn't include **Radar chart**, which is what I would want it to be.

I found a sample of such chart at https://www.drupal.org/files/RadarGraph.png, which looks like so:

[image]

Is there a way I can get that to work?

Answer (score 1):

## Solution 1 - Using module Charts (with Views)

There is no out-of-the-box answer to your question to make this work with the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module, at least not as of today (yet). That's because "Radar chart" is not one of the currently supported chart types (those that are supported are: Pie, Bar, column, Line, Area and Scatter).

But if you're willing (and able) to complete a few extra steps, you should get it to work. Use the details below as a guide, but know also that there are so many options / features in either of the supported charting engines (libraries), i.e. [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery) and [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo). Which is also why it's virtually impossible to support all those options out-of-the-box.

#### Option 1

Refer to the issue about [Stacking column/bar charts](https://www.drupal.org/node/2364091) for an example of how you can do this with a custom module. Comment #3 in it contains a sample like so:

```
<?php
function MYMODULE_chart_alter(&$chart, $chart_id) {
  dsm($chart_id); // Need Developer module enabled for dsm to work
  if ($chart_id == 'MYCHARTVIEW__DISPLAY') { // Watch out for those double underscores
    $chart['#stacking'] = TRUE;
  }
}
?>
```

This should work for both [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery) and [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo) as the charting library (engine).

The remaining challenge for you is what exactly you should specify as chart_id, and which specific charting option is needed for such "radar chart". My best bet, for Highcharts, is that it is what that library calls a "[Polar Chart](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/polar)" (would be too easy for all those charting libraries to use at least the same terminology ...).

#### Option 2

A possible alternative (or maybe refinement, depends on your needs) that you may want to look at is using the approach as described in the issue about [Pass library-specific options via existing #raw_options](https://www.drupal.org/node/2209467), AFTER you apply the [patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/highcharts_raw.patch) in [comment nr 4 of this issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2209467#comment-8638855). If you're using the most recent dev version of the Charts module (which is stable and includes various patches on top of the rc1 release), then this patch is already available (no more need to apply it). Be aware that this only works for Highcharts as of right now (waiting for a similar patch to become available for Google charts also).

Refer to the question about "https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/183018" (and its answers) for an interesting use-case of these "raw options".

## Solution 2 - Using module Forena (without Views)

The sample radar chart in your question is actually from the [Supported chart types](https://www.drupal.org/node/2362447), one of the [Community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2041363) pages from the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module.

The very same sample is also included in **SVG Graph Demo**, one of the samples that gets installed by the Forena module, such as in [this demo site](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/sample.svg_demo).

So such chart can ALSO be created with the Forena module, which uses the (free and open source) [PHP SVG Graph](http://www.goat1000.com/svggraph.php) library, without using [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views). And by using the integration of Forena with the [BEAN](https://www.drupal.org/project/bean) module (as explained in its documentation about [Bean Integration](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/help.sitebuilding#bean), you can put such chart in a block that you'd put on your page where it fits your needs.

For (way) more details, head over to the Forena Documentation included with the module (or its equivalent in the [demo site](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/help)). Or have a look at various questions around here tagged with [forena](/questions/tagged/forena) ... and add your own questions if needed (using this tag).

**Disclosure**: I'm a (co-)maintainer of [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) and [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena).

Comment: Thank you. I never did a custom module before but I'm about to try the option 1. Where should I write the code?

Comment: Interesting NEW challenge (for you)! Somewhere in your custom module, which should go in a new subfolder of your modules folder, whereas you name the subfolder whatever you want (eg: **my_charts)**. In that subfolder you then create the (empty at first) files **my_charts.info**, and a **my_charts.module**. And then you add the relevant code in those (and extra?) files. How to write that code is obviously impossible to include in my answer here (I hope you understand). PS: are you familiar with http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers ?

Comment: Maybe the link in my "note" that I added helps a bit to get you going with your first module?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to install the charts module and activate it. Once this is done, you need to use the chart.js library. You have to modify the charts.charts_types.yml file and add the code below at the end of the file:

```
radar:
  label: 'Radar'
  axis: 'xy'
  axis_inverted: false
  stacking: false
```

Then reload the module page with your browser and empty the caches.